# Can I log data in an policy?

Tags: laravel, logging, policy

I am new to writing policies. I wanna know if I can see data that comes in an policy function.

I have tried googling if it is possible to log something in an policy but I couldn't find anything about this. Now I am just wandering if there is any other possible option to see the data that comes in an policy.

```php
public function show(User $userIdentity, Client $client) {
        \Log::info(['log']);
    }
```

I hope someone has an answer for this or another option for me to see the data that is coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, if you use the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log` facade you will log stuff. It's nothing related to the policies "per se", if the code gets executed, the log will trigger. If you are looking for architectural suggestions, it depends on the big picture. If that's a simple scenario, that will be enough AND will be fine. If you plan to have complex/multiple logs, you probably want to delegate the logging logic to a dedicated object/package and intercept the event trough an observer, for example.

Docs related to the facede usage [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#writing-log-messages) and [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Log.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you have to explicitly call your policy, like

```
$client = Client::find(1);

auth()->user()->can('view', $client);
```

This is discussed in details here [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies)

Dont forget to register your policies

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider; // auth service provider extends service provider so make sure you take a note of this one

class ReferralServiceProvider extends AuthServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        Client::class => ClientPolicy::class
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

-

```
public function show(User $userIdentity, Client $client) {
    logger($userIdentity->toJson());
    logger($client->toJson());
}
```